# How can I get nearest geo coordinate of an input latitude and longitude in Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, geospatial

I have a Cassandra table that has a mapping of locations. It has a column with PointType data and another column with location information. Given a latitude and a longitude as input, I want to find the nearest geocordinate present in my table. Is it possible through a cql query? Are there any other way around?

I attempted to follow the following documentation:
https://docs.datastax.com/en/dse/6.7/cql/cql/cql_using/search_index/queriesGeoSpatial.html

However, I am having difficulty in comprehending it.

Comment: What version of C* are you running? Are you running the DataStax Enterprise 6.7? Could you run `bin/dse -v` (or) `bin/cqlsh -v` and post the output in your original question?